# Proving a sum of matrices is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

A, B are two quadratic matrices and I-AB is invertible.

How do I prove that I-BA is also invertible and (I-BA)^-1 = I + B(I-AB)^-1 * A?

Not sure how to start with, but I have tried:

I-AB = C

⇔ B - BAB = BC

⇔ I - BA = BCB^-1

⇔ I - BA = B(I-CB^-1)

But this does not lead to anything and Im just guessing and I have no strategy. Any tips?

Comment: You just pre-multiply $I+B(I-AB)^{-1}A$ by $(I-BA)$ and check that it is $I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $M^{-1}$ is the inverse of $M$, it suffices to show that $M^{-1}M = I$.

To that end, note that
$$
[I + B(I - AB)^{-1}A](I - BA) = \\
I - BA + B(I - AB)^{-1}A - B(I - AB)^{-1}ABA =\\
I - BA + B[(I - AB)^{-1} - (I - AB)^{-1}AB]A =\\
I - BA + B[(I - AB)^{-1}(I - AB)]A =\\
I - BA + BA = I.
$$
So indeed, $I + B(I - AB)^{-1}A$ is the inverse of $(I - BA)$.

Comment: It is to show also that $MM^{-1}=I$ or *prove* that it is enough wilth a left-inverse only, the latter being non-trivial.

Comment: @A.Γ. I suppose it depends on the linear algebra course, but the sufficiency of left-inverses is a fact I'm used to assuming, non-trivial though it's proof may be. [Here is a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/81360) about this proof, for reference.